# ASP.Net MVC 3 - JSON Model binding to array

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, asp.net-mvc-3, model-binding

I am on ASP.Net MVC 3, and going by the feature list supported in at, i should be able to get default json model binding working out of the box. However i havent been successful in binding an array/collection from json to the action method parameter. Although I did get simple json object binding working right. Would greatly appreciate if an expert here could tell me what i am doing wrong.

Here is the code:

Server side code first:

//Action Method

```
 public JsonResult SaveDiscount(IList<Discount> discounts)
    {
       foreach(var discount in discounts)
       {
       ....
       }
    }
```

//View model

```
public class Discount
{
    string Sku{get; set;}
    string DiscountValue{get; set;}
    string DiscountType{get; set;}

}
```

//client side(jquery/js):

```
    var discount = {};
    var jsondatacoll = [];
    $('#discountgrid tr').each(function () {

        sku = $(this).find("td").eq(1).html();
        discValue = $(this).find('.discval').val();
        discType = $(this).find('.disctype').val();

        discount = { Sku: sku, DiscountType: discType, DiscountValue: discValue};
        jsondatacoll.push(discount);
        }
    })
    if (jsondatacoll.length > 0) {
        var catalogDiscount = JSON.stringify(jsondatacoll);

        $.ajax(
        {
            url: '/url/savediscount',
            type: 'POST',
            data: catalogDiscount,
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
            success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                ...                   
            },
            error: function (objAJAXRequest, strError) {                 
               ...
            }
        }
     );   //ajax
    }
```

i did check the json payload in fiddler and it look like below:

```
[
    {"Sku":"sku1","DiscountType":"type1","DiscountValue":"10"},     
    {"Sku":sku2","DiscountType":"type1","DiscountValue":"12"}, 
    {"Sku":"sku3","DiscountType":"type2","DiscountValue":"40"}
]
```

And on the server side i do see the `IList<Discount>` discounts has been populated with 3 empty `Discount` objects - meaning the properties are null but the length of the discounts argument is 3.

Comment: Your model's properties should be marked `public`. Typo or oversight?

Comment: wow man! that was an oversight!!! would you want to enter this as answer so that i can mark it? :)

Comment: Thanks to the rest of your post being correct (other than those missing 'publics'), I noticed the contentType being set along with using JSON.stringify and it made all the difference.  Struggled with this for hours! Thanks!

Comment: If you like the stuff mentioned in @DanielGill's comment check out this post on sending complex datatypes through ajax http://encosia.com/using-complex-types-to-make-calling-services-less-complex/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

As [Cresnet Fresh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45433/crescent-fresh) rightly pointed out in the comments to the question the model properties must be marked public.

So modifying `Discount` class as below resolved this.

```
public class Discount
{
    public string Sku{get; set;}
    public string DiscountValue{get; set;}
    public string DiscountType{get; set;}

}
```

Comment: Can anyone explain (or better yet link to an explanation) as to WHY this has to be the case? I presume because first an empty object is created (hence need for parameterless constructor) and then the properties are set but I prefer to work on facts, not presumptions.

Answer (score 11):

while [@thanikkal](https://stackoverflow.com/users/629797/thanikkal) answered this particular question, I had the same symptoms and a very similar setup.

instead of the `public` or `{ get; set; }` in my models causing the model binding to not work it was actually my **jQuery** method! (RAWR!)

I was using `$.post` (which didn't work) instead of `$.ajax`.

---

**Doesn't Work:**

> ```
> $.post("/Games/Action",
>    { "userId": "1", "listName": [ { "fooId": "2", "barId": "99" } ] },
>    'json',
>    true
>   );
> ```

The values are in the Form.Data[], but are not mapped properly.

---

**Works:**

> ```
>  $.ajax(
>     {
>         url: '/Games/Action',
>         type: 'POST',
>         data: JSON.stringify({ userId: "1", listName: [ { fooId: 2, barId: 99 } ] }),
>         dataType: 'json',
>         contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8',
>         success: function (data, textStatus, jqXHR)
>         {
>             console.log(data);
>         },
>         error: function (objAJAXRequest, strError)
>         {
>             console.log(data);
>         }
>     });
> ```

All values mapped correctly.

---

Lost a few hours to this one, hope this helps others.

Comment: I can confirm that the above is true. I was using $.post and whilst I was seeing an array being populated in my model, the values were all null. Switching to $.ajax has resolved the issue which seems strange. I was using MVC 4, jQuery 2.0.2

Comment: Just to expand on this a bit more, the $.post() function is shorthand for $.ajax() as explained here: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/. But the call to $.ajax() does not include the contentType attribute. The above solution works for me, but not if I remove the contentType attribute, so it is this in particular which is needed (in my case at least).

Answer (score -1):

Your code looks fine.. But check this

1. Routing settings.
2. Put [HttpPost] attribute on SaveDiscount

and try this

```
var catalogDiscount = JSON.stringify( { discounts: jsondatacoll } );
```

that would give make right data binding.

Comment: thanks for answering here. as explained in the comments above, i missed marking my viewmodel properties public.