# Does MVC3 /.net4 have a method for unpacking a JSONified Javascript array into a C# array of strings?

Tags: c#, javascript, json, asp.net-mvc-3

My MVC3/.Net service is receiving some arguments as a JSONified Javascript array, and I'd like to unpack them into a C# array of strings.

Is there an existing method for doing this, or do I have to write my own?

(currently the data comes in to my controller as a single string, and looks something like this:

```
"[\"string1\", \"string2\", \"string3\"]"
```

Comment: Can you show us your Json data

Comment: Check for JSON.Net that helps serializing to and from the json format

Comment: Why don't you create a model so that when it comes into the controller the default binder will give you an object with its properties set based upon the json data?

Comment: We need to see the action method signature as well..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this should happen via built in binding but without your code to see if there's an issue, can't comment more.

See for example:
[ASP.Net MVC 3 - JSON Model binding to array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284613/asp-net-mvc-3-json-model-binding-to-array)
You shouldn't require JSON.Net

Comment: The jQuery $.post method, used with the syntax in the linked question, jsonifies the object in a way that the built in binding seems to like and the rest is cake.

Answer (score 0):

I originally left a comment but thought I'd jump in with an answer.

If you create a model with the properties marked as public the default binder should return you an object in your controller based upon the incoming JSON data.

```
public MyModel
{
  public string Value1 {get;set;}
  public string Value2 {get;set;}
  public string Value3 {get;set;}
}

public ActionResult MyActionMethod(MyModel model)
{ 
   //oooh model is populated here
}
```

However it looks as though your JSON data is not key/value pairs