# MVC Model binding not working as expected on complex type from AJAX request

Tags: c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4, model-binding

I have a 'ViewModel' I want to pass to my action, and it looks like this:

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MyNumber { get; set; }
}

public class RequestViewModel
{
    public List<MyClass> MyClasses { get; set; }
    public int AnotherNumber { get; set; }
}
```

In javascript, I define my data like so:

```
       var actionRequest = {
            MyClasses: [
                {
                    Id: 1,
                    MyNumber: 30
                },
                {
                    Id: 2,
                    MyNumber: 40,
                }
            ],
            AnotherNumber: 12
        };
```

I make the call:

```
    $.ajax({
        type: "Get",
        url: " /Controller/MyAction",
        data: actionRequest,
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            // Good stuff
        },
        error: function (data) {
            // Bad stuff
        }
    });
```

My action's signature:

```
public ActionResult MyAction(RequestViewModel request)
```

On inspecting `request` (my action is successfully hit), `AnotherNumber` is populated whereas my collection of `MyClass` is `null`.

I'm missing something obvious here, I just don't know what.

## EDIT

I really do appreciate the suggestions and answers so far but none (upto now) have worked, so for now I'm settling for:

```
public class RequestViewModel
{
    public int[] MyClassIds { get; set; }
    public int[] MyNumberValues { get; set; }
    public int AnotherNumber { get; set; }
}
```

It feels horrible doing this, but it's a project that has quite a bit of urgency behind it now so I have to go with what works.

Comment: Take the `dataType: "json"` out? You are telling the request that you're sending a JSON, which is a string, but you are providing an object. Either keep the `dataType` specification **and** stringify the object, or remove the spec.

Comment: @AndreiV - thanks for your suggestion, didn't work though. I was under the impression it was all serialized as part of the request anyway?

Comment: Hmm... something must be off then. I must recheck my sources.

Comment: Yes, it's odd that `AnotherNumber` is populated whereas the list is not.

Comment: I think it's null because of routing.

Comment: a similar question is [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5284613/asp-net-mvc-3-json-model-binding-to-array). You can refer this to get some inputs

Comment: That space in the url seems suspicious. " /Controller" vs "/Controller".

Answer (score 3):

try below code and put the name same as it is in controller as shown below :-

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: " /Controller/MyAction",
        data: :{ request : JSON.stringify(actionRequest) },
        dataType: "json",
        traditional: true,
        success: function (data) {
            // Good stuff
        },
        error: function (data) {
            // Bad stuff
        }
    });
```

and I would suggest try POST request put httpPost attribute above action method as shown below :-

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult MyAction(RequestViewModel request)
```

Comment: have some extra thing as well @Kartikeya and still updating :P

Comment: by default request is get only httpget attribute is not required on controller action.. bro

Comment: ohh ok got it..btw I always get confuse where to put GET and when to put POST..share some knowledge if you know then @Kartikeya

Comment: As per the answer above, the whole object is now null unfortunately.

Comment: I would suggest try using POST @DeeMac

Comment: Maybe try a JsonResult instead of ActionResult?

Answer (score 1):

Try using `JSON.stringify` and modify `data` in ajax request as :

```
data:{ request : JSON.stringify(actionRequest) }
```

and add  `contentType: "application/json"` in your ajax request.

---

OR Try This :

```
var request = {
        MyClasses: [
            {
                Id: 1,
                MyNumber: 30
            },
            {
                Id: 2,
                MyNumber: 40,
            }
        ],
        AnotherNumber: 12
    };

 request = JSON.stringify({ 'request': request });
```

now use `data` in ajax request this way :

```
data: request
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your suggestion, but now the whole object is null on the server.

Comment: @DeeMac...try above answer

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure where the difference is and now I can't reproduce the error but this works for me.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int MyNumber { get; set; }
}

public class RequestViewModel
{
    public List<MyClass> MyClasses { get; set; }
    public int AnotherNumber { get; set; }
}

[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Save(RequestViewModel actionRequestX)
{
        return null;
}

var actionRequest = {
        MyClasses: [
            {
                Id: 1,
                MyNumber: 30
            },
            {
                Id: 2,
                MyNumber: 40
            }
        ],
        AnotherNumber: 12
    };

    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "/Home/Save",
    contentType: "application/json, charset=utf-8",
    data: JSON.stringify({ actionRequestX: actionRequest }),
    dataType: "json",
    traditional: true,
    success: function (data) {
        // Good stuff
    },
    error: function (data) {
        // Bad stuff
    }
});
});
```